# Adding completion Handler to withAnimation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I looked everywhere I want to do some action after animation finishes in swiftUI, but the document doesn't have any mention of completion handler for `withAnimation` in SwiftUI. Is there a way around this. Please help I am a beginner in iOS and SwiftUI.

```
Grid(viewModel.cards) { card in
    CardView(card: card, theme: self.viewModel.getTheme())
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.8)) {
                self.viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
            self.viewModel.resetGame()
        }
        .padding(5)
    }
    HStack {
        Text("Score : \(self.viewModel.score)")
    }
}
```

After `withAnimation` inside `onTapGesture` I want to run `self.viewModel.resetGame()`
I can't use `AnimatableModifier` because I'm inside `onTapGesture`.

Comment: There is no such handler in SwiftUI for now. In referenced post I used an [approach that somehow mimics this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just wrap your reset function to asyncAfter DispatchQueue with length of your animation?

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
self.viewModel.resetGame()
            }
```