# Disable Button While an animation happen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to disable a button in SwiftUI while an animation happens? If i want for example trigger a change of a lenght of a side of a shape then i think the button should be **disabled in that time while the animation happens**. Could i see when the animation is finished with animatableData or something like this?

Comment: You need approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030, pay attention on comment in `animatableData`.