# SwiftUI how to chain 2 animations?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm trying to animate a line moving in a circle then using [this library](https://github.com/markiv/SwiftUI-Shimmer) to add a second shimmer animation.  The problem is they never both work, either one or the other will animate depending how if `conditionIsTrue` how can I chain them so that they work in succession?

```
                      Circle()
                        .animation(.linear, value: 0.8)
                        .if(conditionIsTrue)) { $0.shimmering(active: true, duration: 0.9, bounce: false) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi possibly but I can't quite follow?

Answer (score 0):

Currently no chaining animation in SwiftUI. You can add a delay to the shimmering animation to run it after the first animation