# How to access current value of @Binding during .animation()

Tags: swiftui

How do I access the current value of this animatable property `scaleAmount`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Scale amount", value: $scaleAmount.animation(), in: 1...5)
            Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
                    .onChange(of: scaleAmount) { value in
                        print(value)
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

These are the final values of the animatable property - not the interpolated values used for the animation. Those are what I need.

Is it possible to do this? I have also tried replacing the `.onChange` block to

```
                    .onChange(of: $scaleAmount.animation()) { value in
                        print(value)
                    }
```

But the compiler says that the Binding returned by the `.animation()` call must conform to Equatable.

I have also tried factoring out the Circle view into a custom view and only giving it a CGFloat to work with, and the animation happens. But the view drawing the circle has no binding in it. This gives the same output as the first code snippet.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Scale amount", value: $scaleAmount.animation(), in: 1...5)
            MyCircle(scaleAmount: scaleAmount)
        }
    }
}

struct MyCircle: View {
    var scaleAmount: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        print(scaleAmount)
        return Circle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
    }

}
```

So, the question again: Is it possible to get the current value of `scaleAmount` property as it is being animated?

Comment: In your first example you can do this, to get more info on animation: print(" value: \(value) \n anim: \($scaleAmount.animation())  ")

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// Created by Eric Lightfoot on 2021-06-24.
//

import SwiftUI

/// Use .onBody(observedValue:onBody:) by passing an
/// animatable property along with a closure to execute
/// whenever that property is changed throughout the
/// animation
/// ---
// struct ContentView: View {
//    @State private var scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1
//    @State var scaleText: String = "1.000"
//
//    var body: some View {
//        VStack {
//            Stepper("Scale amount", value: $scaleAmount.animation(), in: 1...5)
//            ZStack {
//                Circle()
//                        .fill(Color.red)
//                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
//                Text(scaleText)
//                        .onBody(for: scaleAmount, onBody: { scaleText = "\($0)" })
//             }
//                    .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
//         }
//     }
// }
/// ---

struct AnimationProgressObserverModifier<Value>: AnimatableModifier where Value: VectorArithmetic {

    /// Some experimenting led to observing the behaviour
    /// that wrapping the observedValue with animatableData
    /// (to conform to the protocol) caused this property
    /// to be set continuously during the animation, instead
    /// of only at the end
    var animatableData: Value {
        get {
            observedValue
        }
        set {
            observedValue = newValue
            runCallbacks()
        }
    }

    /// The animatable property to be observed
    /// passed in at init
    private var observedValue: Value

    /// The block to execute on each animation progress
    /// update
    private var onBody: (Value) -> Void

    init (observedValue: Value, onBody: @escaping (Value) -> Void) {
        self.onBody = onBody
        self.observedValue = observedValue
    }

    /// Run the onBody block provided at init
    /// specifically passing animatable data,
    /// NOT observedValue
    private func runCallbacks () {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            onBody(animatableData)
        }
    }

    func body (content: Content) -> some View {
        /// No modification to view content
        content
    }
}

extension View {
    /// Convenience method on View
    func onBody<Value: VectorArithmetic> (for value: Value, onBody: @escaping (Value) -> Void)
                    -> ModifiedContent<Self, AnimationProgressObserverModifier<Value>> {
        modifier(AnimationProgressObserverModifier(observedValue: value, onBody: onBody))
    }
}
```