# How can I make a custom Animation View modifier in SwiftUI in purpose of accessing internal values for changed Value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want access to internal values of **animation Modifier** for use in my project,

**For example**: I am changing the offset of yellow Circle from **-200.0** to **200.0** with a simple **State** and also I am applying animation Modifier for smooth transition, and I want show the changed value from -200.0 to 200.0, but as all of you know SwiftUI just update View for -200.0 and 200.0, maybe apple SwiftUI team would thought lots about it that they do not need update Views for tiny small changes from -200.0 to 200.0 and they capsulate that part inside of animation modifier, how ever they are some people like me want access those internal values.

**First of all if there is any way to access those values I want to know how?**

**If there is no way** that we can access those sweet values then I want try build a custom animation modifier, which take same input as apple animation modifier, and i want to know how can i make this happen?

Do we have access to apple animation modifier in **github** or some where, I need help for start, also I do not want update offset or the value with a timer or something like that, because those ways force View update their **body** while we are updating our State value in a timer, so that option looks inconvenient or even economically not good in process power.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = -200.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .overlay(Text(String(describing: offset)).bold())
            .offset(y: offset)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: offset)
            .customAnimation(.easeInOut, value: offset)   // <<: Here!!!
            .onTapGesture {
                
                if (offset == -200.0) { offset = 200.0 }
                else { offset = -200.0 }
                
            }
            .shadow(radius: 10.0)
        
    }
    
}


struct CustomAnimationViewModifier<V: Equatable>: ViewModifier {
    
    let animation: Animation?
    let value: V
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        return content
        
        
    }
    
}


extension View {
    
    func customAnimation<V: Equatable>(_ animation: Animation?, value: V) -> some View {
        
        return self.modifier(CustomAnimationViewModifier(animation: animation, value: value))
        
    }
    
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030?