# SwiftUI - How to have a one time animation state

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a game with two players, each player has a score represented as a Text.
When one score changes, I want the score animate so i'm using ScaleEffect.

But in order to have the animation run I need to change a State variable. And I want this state to reset after the animation finishes so I could call it again afterwards.

Is there a way to do that without a asyncAfter? This feels very primitive and unsafe.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to implement animations in a SwiftUI view?

Comment: No, I know how to implement animations. But after the animation ends, the state is still true. If the score changes, I want to set it to true again. I want to know if there's a better way to reset the state than asyncAfter

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for some reason but that's what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for some reason but that's what I needed. Thanks

Comment: It shouts: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."