# How to start the second animation after first animation ends?

Tags: swiftui

When I press button the animation shows (Insertion). I want it to automatically trigger the second animation (removal) without pressing the button after first transition end. That means I want to show and then hide the transition automatically when I press the button only one time. How to do that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    
    
    @State private var WidgetSelectionShowState: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        //Color.purple
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.white)
                .zIndex(0) //
            Button ("show", action:  {
                
                withAnimation {
                    WidgetSelectionShowState.toggle()
                }
            })
            
            if (WidgetSelectionShowState) {
                
                popupPage ()
                
            }
        }  .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        
    }
}


struct popupPage: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("This is a popup")
            
            
            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.green)
                .zIndex(0) //this is the layer order.
            
        }.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
        . frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center )
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi I still don't get how it can be connected to this code.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it in the following way. I am not sure if it works in more complex scenarios though. If someone has concerns about this solution please comment!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    
    @State private var showState: Bool = false
    let animationDuration: Double = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            
            Button("Show", action:  {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (animationDuration * 2)) {
                    showState = false
                }
                
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: animationDuration)
                    .repeatCount(2, autoreverses: true)) {
                        showState.toggle()
                        
                    }
            })
            
            if (showState) {
                
                PopupPage()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
            }
            
        }
    }
}


struct PopupPage: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle ()
                .fill(.green)
            
            Text("This is a popup")
        }
        . frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center )
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed some observations on your code: variables are usually written in camel case, with the first letter being lowercased. Classes and structs, in camel case but capitalized. In a z stack, you in general do not need to set the z index. Views declared first in the z stack are placed behind views declared after them. I changed the color of one Rectangle so that I could see it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find on the internet a solution involving completion handlers. I was afraid of creating a pyramid of doom, and I also thought we were moving away from DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter with the introduction of Combine and publishers, and swiftui. anyways here is my animation, I had to write an exhaustive script without using map or a for loop which I prefered.

```html
    func animate() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1)) {
                selectedIndex = -1
                previousIndex = 1

            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1)) {
                selectedIndex = 1
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1)) {
                selectedIndex = -1
                previousIndex = 2

            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1)) {
                selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use delays for that, without resorting to DispatchQueue.