# SwiftUI Animation Circle with Colors

Tags: animation, swiftui

My problem is simple I think but I can't figure how solve it.
I've this :

```
struct ArcSelectionView: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    @Binding var curColor: Color
    @Binding var colorToPress: Color
    @Binding var score: Int
    
    @State var colors = [Color.blue, Color.red, Color.green, Color.yellow]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(1 ..< 5, id: \.self) { item in
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: self.isShowing ? CGFloat((Double(item) * 0.25) - 0.25) : CGFloat(Double(item) * 0.25),
                          to: CGFloat(Double(item) * 0.25))
                    .stroke(self.colors[item - 1], lineWidth: 50)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if colors[item - 1] == colorToPress {
                            score += 1
                        }
                        isShowing.toggle()
                        colorToPress = colors.randomElement() ?? Color.offWhite
                        colors.shuffle()
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35) {
                            self.isShowing.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.isShowing ? 0 : 180))
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.35))
    }
}
```

If I didn't shuffle colors in the .onTapGesture, everything is ok. But If I do, I've a strange plain Circle that appears in the middle and disappear after. It's ugly. [Ugly Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB6NM.png)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I can only reproduce from time to time ... usually on the first few clicks, then everything looks good.  Did you also test on a real device?  – running on Xcode 13.2.1 and iPhone 12 Simulator 15.2 – actually pretty cool animation :)

Comment: it has to with the `colors.shuffle()` - without that everything works!

Comment: @ChrisR Yes totally, the shuffle fucked up ... But I need it, it's for a game and I want to shuffle the order of colors after each tap. On the simulator I've 0 problem, only on device. Maybe the frame rate ?

Comment: I suppose the shuffle while already redrawing makes the problem. can you disconnect both steps? either wait for the shuffle to have ended, or pre-shuffle into an array ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the animation of the `Circles`. The better solution is to use arc shapes. Here is a working solution:

```
struct ArcSelectionView: View {
    @Binding var curColor: Color
    @Binding var colorToPress: Color
    @Binding var score: Int
    
    @State private var colors = [Color.blue, Color.red, Color.green, Color.yellow]
    @State private var pct: CGFloat = 0.25
    @State private var originalPCT: CGFloat = 0.25
    
    let duration: Double = 0.35
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CircleView(wedge: originalPCT)
            // I am not sure why, but at there is a difference of 10 in the sizes of the
            // circle and the modifier. This corrects for it so the touch is accurate.
                .frame(width: 310, height: 310)
            
            PercentageArc(Color.clear, colors: colors, pct: pct) {
                // With this solution you must have the callback sent to
                // the main thread. This was unnecessary with AnimatbleModifier.
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    pct = originalPCT
                }
            }
            .animation(.linear(duration: duration), value: pct)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            // This forces the view to ignore taps.
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .onAppear {
            pct = 1.0 / CGFloat(colors.count)
            originalPCT = pct
        }
    }
    
    func CircleView(wedge: CGFloat) -> some View {
        
        ZStack {
            // Array(zip()) is a cleaner and safe way of using indices AND you
            // have the original object to use as well.
            ForEach(Array(zip(colors, colors.indices)), id: \.0) { color, index in
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: CGFloat((Double(index) * wedge)),
                          to: CGFloat(Double(index + 1) * wedge))
                // The color of the stroke should match your background color.
                // Clear won't work.
                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if color == colorToPress {
                            score += 1
                            print("score!")
                        }
                        pct = 0
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
                            colorToPress = colors.randomElement() ?? .white
                            colors.shuffle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct PercentageArc<Content>: View, Animatable where Content: View {
    private var content: Content
    private var colors: [Color]
    private var pct: CGFloat
    
    private var target: CGFloat
    private var onEnded: () -> ()
    
    init(_ content: Content, colors: [Color], pct: CGFloat, onEnded: @escaping () -> () = {}) {
        self.content = content
        self.colors = colors
        self.pct = pct
        self.target = pct
        self.onEnded = onEnded
    }
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { pct }
        set { pct = newValue
            // newValue here is interpolating by engine, so changing
            // from previous to initially set, so when they got equal
            // animation ended
            if newValue == target {
                onEnded()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ForEach(Array(zip(colors, colors.indices)), id: \.0) { color, index in
                    ArcPortionShape(pct: pct, startAngle: .degrees(1.0 / CGFloat(colors.count) * CGFloat(index) * 360.0))
                        .foregroundColor(color)
                }
            )
    }
    
    struct ArcPortionShape: InsettableShape {
        let pct: CGFloat
        let startAngle: Angle
        var insetAmount = 0.0
        
        init(pct: CGFloat, startAngle: Angle) {
            self.pct = pct
            self.startAngle = startAngle
            
        }
        var portion: CGFloat {
            pct * 360.0
        }
        
        var endAngle: Angle {
            .degrees(startAngle.degrees + portion)
        }
        
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            
            var p = Path()
            
            p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2.0, y:rect.height / 2.0),
                     radius: rect.height / 2.0 + 5.0,
                     startAngle: startAngle,
                     endAngle: endAngle,
                     clockwise: false)
            
            return p.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 50))
        }
        
        func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
            var arc = self
            arc.insetAmount += amount
            return arc
        }
        
    }
}
```

Originally, I made this with an `AnimatableModifier`, but it is deprecated, and the solution using it fails if it is placed in ANY stack or `NavigationView`. I can see why `AnimatableModifier` is deprecated.

This solution draws inspiration from [this answer from Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/7129318), for the callback idea, though the solution will not work in iOS 15.2.

Comment: Thank you! Animation isn't smooth like the first one but it works nicely. :)

Comment: Not smooth in what way? I didn't see anything wrong when testing.

Comment: This has done most of my work but what if I want to create a different proportion of arc eg i have 4 arcs with 10% , 20% , 30%, 40% ???? How to do that

Comment: You can make a `struct` that has both a color and a percentage as a parameter, in `PercentageArc` change the [colors] array to an array of that struct and eliminate the `pct` parameter, and use the values in the struct for the color and percent to be sent to `ArcPortionShape`. `ArcPortionShape` will render any arc in a color that you want. And, `PercentageArc` would be able to handle any number of color and arc combinations, up to what the human eye could distinguish on the screen.