# Accessing the current transaction and animation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building a custom navigation flow that acts similar to the default navigation stack model except without the push/pop animation. Essentially, my navigation flow is a paged flow that's changes page by updating state. There are elements in common to every page, such as a progress bar that represents your progress through the flow and those elements can't easily be represented in a standard navigation flow.

I achieved this by doing:

```swift
@State
var offset: CGFloat = 0

GeometryReader { geometry in 
    ZStack {
        Page1()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
        Page2()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .offset(x: offset + geometry.size.width * 2, y: 0)
        Page3()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .offset(x: offset + geometry.size.width * 3, y: 0)
    }
    .onChange(of: page) {
        withAnimation {
            switch page {
            case .first: 
                offset = 0
            case .second:
                offset = geometry.size.width
            case .third:
                offset = geometry.size.width * 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem:

When navigating backwards through this flow, I can rapidly hit the back button and the back button will change the state as fast as I can hit it which looks jarring. What I'd like is to disable the back button, which is always present in the top left of every page, during the page animation. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to detect if an animation is currently happening. Ideally I'd like an `@Environment` property that I can access and use to toggle my button disabled state and I am able to get the current animation via the `transaction` modifier, unfortunately I'm unable to propagate that value into the environment reliably.

Is there a reliable way to hook into the animation system so that I can detect the beginning and start of it? I know that there are view modifiers one can create to give animations a completion block but I'd rather stay away from those if at all possible. It also seems somewhat folly given that some hypothetical `isAnimating` environment value would be true for *any* animation happening, not just my page one.

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030.