# Track if view is being animated

Tags: swiftui

Assuming i have a button is being animated. How do we track that this button is being animated? I read Apple document but did not find anything.

My goal are: 1. Get animating data and 2. prevent this button from triggering while the animation is still going on.

```
Button("label") {
 action
}
```

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030.

Comment: https://github.com/globulus/swiftui-animation-observer maybe you can make use of this.